# ASP.NET: What is the best chat room component out there?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, components, chatroom

What are all the best / most popular ASP.NET AJAX chat room components out there and how do they weigh in terms of robustness, flexibility, portability?

Answer (score 6):

HTTP chat set ups suck. GMails fails all the time and Facebook's isn't much better. Please, for all our sakes use a Flash or Silverlight app for this.

Comment: It's nice to pick on HTTP, but since we're dealing with websites, and clients behind firewalls, it's often the only way. Silverlight chat samples also use HTTP for the exact same reason.

Comment: Gidon even that is far more reliable than using the browser.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX chat is awful because HTTP is a terrible protocol for two-way push communication. For the sake of your users, please take a different route.

(I see this is practically the same as [@Spencer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419633/asp-net-what-is-the-best-chat-room-component-out-there/1419659#1419659). UV that :) )